# How to show the time a link was visited next to the link?

Tags: css, google-chrome, stylish

How to show when a link was visited next to itself in Chrome?

For example using Stylish I changed the color of visited links with:

```
a.link:visited>* { color:#cc00ff ! important }
```

Now I'm stuck trying to show the time of the visit next to the link, please help.

Comment: Do you have that information?

Comment: @NielsNet Yes, it is my own browsing history, of course

Comment: Good question. I looked at MDN and found this, maybe this is it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/search

Comment: Stylish cannot do this. CSS cannot do this. Tampermonkey cannot do this.  You must write an extension to to do that.